# How to avoid folder name in URL

Tags: presentation, urls

I have site definition up to C.

[image]

When accessing the properties in the URL Property page name is displayed. How to avoid it?

Current Url:Http:/Sitename/en/Propert Page/PropertyName

Expected URL:http:/Sitename/en/PropertyName

I tried Alias name didn't work. I searched and tried IIS redirect it also didn't work.

Anyone handled this scenario with simpler approach kindly guide me.

Comment: You need to implement a rewrite processor. There are some modules on sitecore marketplace which allows you to perform url rewriting

Comment: The simplest solution is to _move_ the pages. If you don't want to do that then re-think your information architecture because it is wrong. Maybe rename _Property Page_ to _Properties_ and make it a listing page instead of creating hacks to resolve it.

Answer (score 1):

You can look into the below solution:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/20605991/4129621

you have to override LinkProvider and ItemResolver for that as mentioned in above URL.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done using the sitecore alias. I'm not sure how you create alias. I have implemented this for one of my projects.

**Sitecore Content Tree**

- Home

  - Blog

    - Categories

      - Cricket
      - Football

If you want to access a cricket page, url would be **http://sitecore.local/blog/categories/cricket**

But client wanted this page to be access like **http://sitecore.local/blog/cricket**

we have created an alias url as follows.
1. First create a alias item for Blog
2. Under Blog item, create an alias for Cricket and map the url to categories/cricket.
3. Do the similiar step for football. It will resolve your issue.

Another step: 
You have create your custom link provider & check for that particular page template. If you find, write your logics as per your requirement.
https://gist.github.com/Adamsimsy/4c4af66a53d3b7ba2ebef5a46c067ca7

Comment: i have 183 properties do i need to create alias name for all properties